# How can I prove this theorem for the maximum singular value of a matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values

Let $A \in \mathbb C^{p \times q}$ and $B \in \mathbb C^{q \times p}$. Let $\bar\sigma(A)$ be the largest singular value of $A$, and let $\rho(AB)$ be the spectral radius of $AB$, which is the maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $AB$. Suppose that $I - AB$ is singular, such that $\text{det}(I - AB) = 0$. How can I show that
$$
\max_{\bar\sigma(B) \leq 1} \rho(AB) = \bar\sigma(A)
$$
So far, I was able to show that
$$
\min_{B \in \mathbb C^{q \times p}} \left\{\bar\sigma(B) \mid \text{$I - AB$ is singular}\right\} = \frac{1}{\bar\sigma(A)}
$$
If the above theorem is true, which I know it is, then
$$
\frac{1}{\displaystyle\max_{\bar\sigma(B) \leq 1} \rho(AB)} = \min_{B \in \mathbb C^{q \times p}} \left\{\bar\sigma(B) \mid \text{$I - AB$ is singular}\right\}
$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed any further.

Comment: How do you define $\overline{\sigma}(A),$ when $A$ is not a square matrix ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I'm not sure what you mean. Why wouldn't $\bar\sigma(A)$ be defined when $A$ isn't a square matrix? Aren't singular values defined for any matrix? And so the largest singular value is just the largest one of these singular values?

Comment: I guess you mean the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yes that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it because it is false. Counterexamples:

1. Suppose $\|A\|_2<1$. Note that it is in general true that
   $$
   \rho(AB)\le\|AB\|_2\le\|A\|_2\|B\|_2\le\|A\|_2\quad\text{whenever $\|B\|_2\le1$,}\tag{$\ast$}
   $$
   Therefore, if $\|A\|_2<1$ and $\|B\|_2\le1$, we will have $\rho(AB)<1$ and hence $I-AB$ is nonsingular. Therefore $\max_{\|B\|_2\le1,\,\det(I-AB)=0}\rho(AB)$ is undefined because no $B$ satisfies the given constraints.
2. Suppose $A=kuu^\ast$ for some $k>1$ and for some unit vector $u$. The set $\left\{B:\,\|B\|_2\le1\text{ and }I-AB\text{ is singular}\right\}$ is non-empty in this case (take e.g. $B=\frac{1}{k}I$). However, as the rank of $AB$ is at most one, $I-AB$ is singular if and only if the spectrum of $AB$ is $\{1,0,\ldots,0\}$. It follows that $\rho(AB)=1<k=\|A\|_2$.

**Edit.** If you do not require $I-AB$ to be singular, it is true that $\max_{\|B\|_2\le1}\rho(AB)=\|A\|_2$. In this case, as shown in $(\ast)$, $\rho(AB)$ is always bounded above by $\|A\|_2$. Hence it suffices to show that $\rho(AB)=\|A\|_2$ for some $\|B\|_2=1$. Let $u$ and $v$ be two unit vectors such that $Av=\|A\|_2u$. That is, $v$ is a right singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value of $A$. Let $B=vu^\ast$. Then $\|B\|_2=1$ and $\rho(AB)=\rho(Avu^\ast)=\rho(\|A\|_2uu^\ast)=\|A\|_2$.

Comment: Not sure I follow your first counterexample. Could you please explain how the set $\left\{B:\,\|B\|_2\le1\text{ and }I-AB\text{ is singular}\right\}$ being empty implies that $$\max_{\bar\sigma(B) \leq 1} \rho(AB) \neq \bar\sigma(A)$$

Comment: @mhdadk You cannot speak of $\rho(AB)$ when $B$ does not exist. The maximum of $\rho(AB)$ is not defined when $B$ is chosen from an empty set.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm curious: if the restriction that $I - AB$ is singular is dropped, is the statement $$\max_{\bar\sigma(B) \leq 1} \rho(AB) = \bar\sigma(A)$$ still false?

Comment: I see. If I modify my question to drop this restriction, could you possibly provide a proof in your answer? Or in the comments, that's also fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!